# using ABS and decimal arithmetic in SQL statement

Tags: sql, decimal

I have a row of type float that can go from 0 to 1.  I want to order my results by the ones closest to 0.5.  So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY ABS(a.value - 0.5) desc
```

But it's not working.  It's just returning ones with 0, then 1, then 0 (it seems random).  Any ideas?

Table a has a row called value, for example:

```
A value = 1
B value = 0
C value = 0.5
D value = 0.3
```

I want it to return them in this order:

```
C (ABS(value - 0.5) = 0)
D (ABS(value - 0.5) = 0.2)
A (ABS(value - 0.5) = 0.5)
B (ABS(value - 0.5) = 0.5)
```

Comment: Paste some sample data and desired output..

Comment: Sorry I'm dumb!  I should have done ASC not DESC...

Answer (score 1):

```
    select abs((a.value-0.5)) as x from a order by x asc;
    x
    ----------
    0.0
    0.2
    0.5
    0.5
```

This assumes that that the type of value is float not integer, I tested float, but not integer.